# Using the method of differential absorption to determine the ethanol content of an unknown sample

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration, ir-spectroscopy, absorption

I have completed a whole set of FITR-ATR spectra analysing 6 solutions of ethanol-water mixtures, all at different concentrations of each.

I have now been instructed to use the method of differential absorption to determine the concentration of ethanol. I am subtracting the absorbance at the base of the C-H stretch of ethanol from the maximum absorbance of the same stretch so now I have a difference in absorbance value. At this stage, I am a little confused as to how I use this value to obtain the concentration of ethanol. All I know is that the Beer-Lambert law is involved somehow.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The absorbance is proportional to the concentration of ethanol.

Comment: See [Beer–Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law)

Comment: @Dave, Can you add more details? Are you correcting the baseline?

Comment: A starter: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_i_use_FT-IR_spectroscopy_in_quantitative_analysis